# What does the 1st line of code do here?

Tags: javascript

```
function Bird() { }
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
let duck = new Bird();
duck.constructor // function Animal(){...}
```

I dont understand the 1st line of code is it an `Object` or a `Contstructor Function`?

Comment: It's a constructor function that doesn't do anything other than act as a constructor and supply a prototype for new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually creating a blueprint for the Bird object from which you can create other objects (duck in your case) from the Animal blueprint. Using prototype you can change its properties and behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It declares a function type named Bird, the brackets are needed even if you dont pass parameteters ( because of it being a function) , then it comes the definition of the function, which you seem you left it on blank.